# Caption not visible under image due to image size

Tags: highslide

I am currently trying to create an image slideshow with captions underneath. However, the images can be very large and (especially on smaller screens or tablets) sometimes they fill up the whole screen. This also means that the caption underneath falls off the page.

Is there a way to automatically fix the image size so that it always leaves enough room for the caption underneath?

This is the HTML of the offending element, if that helps:

```
<a class="highslide" id="thumbnail1" href="/uploads/tx_extsluiter/m3d-server.png" onclick="return hs.expand(this, new captionId( 'galleryF' + 8, 'gallery8-1-caption') )" ><img src="typo3temp/pics/b21b5af80c.png" width="235" height="133" border="0" alt=""></a>
<div style="display: none" class="highslide-caption" id='gallery8-1-caption'><div><p class="bodytext">Hallo, dit is afbeelding 1</p></div></div>
<a class="iteminfo viewlarge" onclick="document.getElementById('thumbnail1').onclick()" >+</a>
<a class="iteminfo viewtooltip tooltip" title="&lt;p class=&quot;bodytext&quot;&gt;Hallo, dit is afbeelding 1&lt;/p&gt;">i</a>
```

I have moved the div directly after the A. It seems that it is now working properly when calculating the height of the image in a high vertical low horizontal browser window, but when using a very wide and low window, the image gets too high. It will fill the whole height of the window, leaving no room for the caption.

Answer (score 1):

If you're putting your caption into the proper highslide-caption div, the expander automatically leaves enough room for that caption. Can we have a link to your live page?

Comment: Unfortunately the website is not publicly viewable right now. Highslide seems to be reserving just enough room to show the actual image, because shrinking the screen does make the image smaller. But the caption always falls off the bottom.

Comment: You're on the right track - the highslide-caption div must immediately follow the "a href."

Comment: Looking into the problem further... I have moved the caption directly after the href, but this has not solved all of the problems. It seems highslide is having some trouble scaling the image horizontally.
If I make my browser smaller horizontally than vertically, it works just fine. But if the width of my screen is bigger than the height (like a widescreen monitor on fullscreen) it doesn't work because the picture takes up all of the available horizontal area on the screen, which leaves too little space for the caption at the bottom.

Comment: We really are going to need access to the live page, because it's not just the HTML snippet that you've posted that controls the image display. We need to see the highslide configuration options that have been set, and perhaps the CSS, as well.

Comment: @Erik Are you using `hs.wrapperClassName = 'floating-caption';` (or `floating-caption` in combination with other `wrapperClassName`) for your gallery? If so, you need to add extra `hs.marginBottom` for your gallery to make room for the caption since this type of caption isn’t part of the wrapper for the popup.